# Query builder using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-queue

I am just beginning my journey into PHP Zend Framework World. The aim of my application is to develop query builder using Zend. This application will be used by many users in a network at same time. When a user performing search based on some conditions provided by the application, the system will fetch the relevant search results from the large database (More than 50 Million Records or even more).

**Note:** One user can perform multiple search requests at a time. Each request creates a unique queue id.

Due to more load in the search result page, it will take some time to display the results. 
So, I have an idea in order to achieve the user friendly environment. Once the user performed the search, he/she can navigate to any other web page, once all the request are completed, an alert or notification will be shown to the user that the search results are ready to view.

According to the queue id, the user can switch back to the search result page and see their results. I had tried with Zend Queue from (http://dennisgurnick.com/2011/09/29/zend-queue-with-mysql/); it’s only for sending emails one by one.  So, please tell me, how to achieve this, your answers are much appreciated.